# Nginx force download mp3 files

Tags: nginx, download, header, webserver, mp3

Inside `/var/www/storage/` folder located only mp3 files. What I want to do is, to make every request to those files to end up with download rather than playing in browser.

My current config looks like this, I can't figure out what is wrong.

```
  server {
       charset utf-8;
       client_max_body_size 128M;

       listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
       server_name dl.domain.com;
       root        /var/www/storage/;
       location / {
            add_header Content-Disposition: "$request_filename";
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your initial configuration is almost correct, all you are forgetting is the "attachment":

```
 add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=$request_filename";
```

It's also recommended that you do the application/octet-stream as suggested by raven428. However I believe you will get the "save as" in most UAs without adjusting the Content-Type.

Per [RFC 2616 sec19.5.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) :

> If this header is used in a response with the application/octet- stream content-type, the implied suggestion is that the user agent should not display the response, but directly enter a `save response as...' dialog.

Answer (score 0):

browser decision to play or download depends on `content-type` header. if you want to force browser download file instead of play, your webserver should return `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` for mp3 files:

```
location ~ /mp3folder/.+\.mp3$ {
 types {
  application/octet-stream;
 }
}
```